# Xamarin / Xamarin.Forms - Deadlock when initializing MasterDetailPage?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Xamarin.Forms App. In the first step the user of the app has to login on a login page which is a simple ContentPage.  After the user succesfully logged in he should see a MasterDetailPage.

My Problem now is that this code line produces a deadlock. So this code line will never finish.

**_masterPage.Master = _mainMenuPage;**

Here is the whole function:

```
  private void SignInButtonClicked(string username, string password)
    {
        SignInAsync(username, password).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Result)
            {
                _signInPage.StopActivityIndicator();

                _masterPage.Master = _mainMenuPage;
                _masterPage.Detail = _masterNavigationPage;
                MainPage = _masterPage;
            }

        }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

SignInAsync:

```
    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> SignInAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        bool signedIn = true;

        //ToDo SignIn logic

        if (signedIn)
        {
            _mainMenuPage = new CPM.Arda.Mobile.Freelancer.Ui.Pages.MainMenu(this);
            await _mainMenuPage.InitAsync();
            await _mainMenuPage.RefreshDataAsync();

            _mainMenuPage.MainMenuItemSelectedEvent += MainMenuItemSelected;

            CPM.Arda.Mobile.Freelancer.Ui.Pages.General.Overview overviewPage = new CPM.Arda.Mobile.Freelancer.Ui.Pages.General.Overview(this);
            await overviewPage.InitAsync();
            await overviewPage.RefreshDataAsync();

            _masterNavigationPage = new Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage(overviewPage);

            _masterPage = new CPM.Arda.Mobile.Freelancer.Ui.Pages.Master(this);
            await _masterPage.InitAsync();
            await _masterPage.RefreshDataAsync();
        }

        return signedIn;
    }
```

Any ideas? It seems very strange to me.

Comment: What do `InitAsync` and `RefreshDataAsync` do?

Comment: At the moment nothing. Just empty methods for future work. I think the code inside SignInAsync is not the problem because SignInAsync finished without problems an ContinueWith is called.

Comment: Try to comment out things that you don't need right now and see what happens, that way you can better pinpoint what is causing the code to hang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I forgot to set the Title property on CPM.Arda.Mobile.Freelancer.Ui.Pages.MainMenu (the MasterPage from the MasterDetailPage). A common mistake with Xamarin.Forms.

But with no exception its very hard to find. Xamarin is not helpful sometimes :/

Comment: This is a known issue: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54477